# Difference between C# and LabWindows/CVI

Tags: c#, labwindows

I am new to LabWindows/CVI. Can anyone please explain, what is the major difference between LabWindows/CVI and C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, they're *completely* different.

C# is a *language*, developed primarily by Microsoft, usually targeting the .NET framework.

LabWindows/CVI is (according to the [documentation](http://www.ni.com/lwcvi/whatis/)):

> LabWindows/CVI is a proven ANSI C development environment for test and measurement that increases the productivity of engineers and scientists.

In other words, it's an IDE for a different language (C), along with tools and libraries particularly suitable for engineers and scientists.

Answer (score 1):

**LabWindows/CVI** is a proven ANSI C development environment for test and measurement that increases the productivity of engineers and scientists. It has a powerful tool for writing data acquisition programs.

**[C# (C Sharp)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)** on the other hand, is an object-oriented programming (.NET) language from Microsoft. It is intended to be a simple, modern, general-purpose, object-oriented programming language.